# Is the space of probability measures on $d$-dimensional Euclidean space separable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of all probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, is $\mathcal{M}$ separable (in the total variation norm or the $L^1$-Wasserstein norm)?

We know from the Lebesgue decomposition theorem that any measure can be decomposed into the sum of an absolutely continuous (w.r.t the Lesbegue measure) part ($\mu_a$), a discrete part ($\mu_d$), and a singular continuous part $\mu_s$. For the first two it is possible construct sequences that converge to them. For the the third however I can't think of an intuitive way to construct such a sequence.

I know that it depends on what $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{F}$ these measures are defined on. In case $\mathcal{F}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ then is it possible to prove/disprove separability?

Comment: Hint (for total variation norm, I don't know the other one): What is the distance of $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$ for $x \neq y$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Bounded from below therefore not separable (since$\delta_x, x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an uncountable set). I added the total variation norm for completeness. The second one is the more interesting case I feel. Its the norm which metrizes the weak topology of probability measures and is also often referred to as the Monge-Kantorovich distance in optimal transport theory

Comment: @PhoemueX in case you're interested - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric

Comment: The wikipedia page you linked says "For any p ≥ 1, the metric space (Pp(M), Wp) is separable, and is complete if (M, d) is separable and complete.[2]" :)

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes that is correct. I believe however this refers only to measures defined on $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$. As I mentioned in the latter part of the question it is possible to prove this. But I'm curious about the case in which we have the Lesbegue $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: This allows more exotic measures like the Cantor distribution for example

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. Then the problem is more difficult... But I nevertheless think that singular continuous measure also exist on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55974/discussion-between-almosteverywhere-and-phoemuex).

Comment: "Of course if $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, then measures of type three won't exist." *Of course* this is false.

Comment: Yes. I have realised this . Will edit the question to indicate the same. Thanks